# React-Router Broken after changing from hashLocation to browserLocation

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I can't figure out why after **changing from hashLocation to now using  browserLocation** that after I am able to click the link below to navigate to (render the interview) the interview, but now for some reason once I'm at the interview (I am redirected to the interview component that renders), if I refresh my browser and try to hit `interviews/companies/:companyId` again when I'm on that same page already, it instead hits my page not found in my express.js implementation.

So again, **summarizing this**: first time around when I click the link from my main landing page which is where that `<Link>` resides..when i first load the website, when I click that...it's able to hit interviews/companies/:companyId and render the interview component.  All is good, until after you try to hit refresh, it bombs out.  Not sure why

**server.js**

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express'),
    app = module.exports = express(),
    port = process.env.PORT || 3000,
    path = require('path');

app.use(express.static('client'));

app.use(function (req, res) {
    res.send('Sorry, Page Not Found');
});


console.log("port we're about to run on: " + port);

app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Ready on port %d', port);
}).on('error', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

On my main landing page, **I click a link** that's defined like this in one of my React Components:

```
 <Link to={`/interviews/companies/${company.id}`}
      params={{id: company.id}}
      className="ft-company"
      ref="link">
    {company.name}
</Link>
```

which initially works fine.  I am sent to /interviews/companies/6 for example and it renders my interview component just fine

**Here's my route definitions:**

```
const App = Component({
    render() {
        return (
            <Router history={browserHistory} onUpdate={() => window.scrollTo(0, 0)}>
                <Route path="/">
                    <IndexRoute component={HomePage}/>
                    <Route name="interview" path="interviews/companies/:companyId" component={Interview}/>
                </Route>
                <Route path="/" component={Container}></Route>
            </Router>
        );
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add entry in your webserver to serve the index.html for every get html request .

**Import the library:**

```
var history = require('connect-history-api-fallback');
```

**Now you only need to add the middleware to your application like so:**

```
var connect = require('connect');

var app = connect()
  .use(history())
  .listen(3000);
```

**Of course you can also use this piece of middleware with express:**

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
app.use(history());
```

https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback

Comment: only problem is now, when I refresh the page refreshes but my images break

Comment: You should serve images from the static directory, try moving this middleware after your static one

Comment: what do you mean by moving what middleware?  my images are in the client folder...

Comment: sorry images should work fine this connect api fallback only modifies the request which are not images or resources. your resources should work fine.See the network whats the failure code and issue .
This plugin works fine and is a standard approach